# How to solve css selector conflit

Tags: html, css

Recently I download a Tab Navigation from https://codyhouse.co/gem/responsive-tabbed-navigation/ here and integrated it to my existing project but all my current project getting problem, because in that extension in side the css file they are used the selector like *::after a,ul,li ... so my design was conflict and now shown ugly. So I tried to add a extra div before the tabstrip html code and modify the tabstrip css code like below

```css
/* CSS Code (existing) */

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*::after,
*::before {
  content: '';
}
/* CSS Code(I modified) */

#tabstrip,
#tabstrip::after,
#tabstrip::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#tabstrip::after,
tabstrip::before {
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div id="tabstrip">

  <header>
    <h1>Responsive Tabbed Navigation</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="cd-tabs">
    <nav>
      <ul class="cd-tabs-navigation">
        <li><a data-content="inbox" class="selected" href="#0">Inbox</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-content="new" href="#0">New</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-content="gallery" href="#0">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-content="store" href="#0">Store</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-content="settings" href="#0">Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li><a data-content="trash" href="#0">Trash</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- cd-tabs-navigation -->
    </nav>

    <ul class="cd-tabs-content">
      <li data-content="inbox" class="selected">
        Test
      </li>

      <li data-content="new">
        Test
      </li>

      <li data-content="gallery">
        Test
      </li>

      <li data-content="store">
        Test
      </li>

      <li data-content="settings">
        Test
      </li>

      <li data-content="trash">
        Test
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- cd-tabs-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-tabs -->

</div>
```

But no use, can you please help me how can I uniquely identify the all css code.

Comment: Hi have a look this https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/fybf3w0v/ let me know if you looking for something more

Comment: if you want to apply css to all inner elements then can use #tabstrip > * as i don't know whats in your code CSS. please let me know if you still having trouble

Comment: Please spellcheck your question title.

Comment: @Monica Thank you, it is working perfect

Comment: @MerbinJo if you don't mind could you please give points for this one to me if i post my answer. i have to be greedy for the stupid point for the job i have applied. :(

Comment: @Monica sorry, I don't have enough points for voteup.

Comment: All Good mate @MerbinJo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Css Pseudo use '>' to apply all inner elements [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/UserIsMonica/fybf3w0v/)

```
  #tabstrip > *, #tabstrip > *::after, #tabstrip > *::before {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
     }

  #tabstrip > *::after, tabstrip > *::before {
    content: '';
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead. Your modified code removed the "all" selector. The code below will now do the same thing it was meant to do, but only for things wrapped with your `tabstrip` ID.

```
#tabstrip *, #tabstrip *::after, #tabstrip *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#tabstrip *::after, tabstrip *::before {
  content: '';
}
```